# How to create path for users and admin after signed in rails 5

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a created a rails 5 app using devise gem that has both a user and admin sign in. They are separate modals and have found in my lessons and created the logic for the admin to be directed to the dashboard after signing in however what is the best method to direct the user to the home page after signing in. Below is my set up for the admin and it works for the admin however when I sign in as the user they are directed to the dashboard as well. Outcome I need to see is the user goes to home page after signing in and admin goes to dashboard.

```
routes:
    root 'pages#home'




    devise_for :users,
                          path: '',
                          path_names: {sign_in: 'user_login', sign_out: 
'user_logout', edit: 'user_profile', sign_up: 'user_registration'},
                          controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 
'users/omniauth_callbacks', registrations: 'registrations' }


    devise_for :admins,
                         path:'',
                         path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 
'logout', edit: 'profile', sign_up: 'registration'},
                         controllers: { omniauth_callbacks: 
'admins/omniauth_callbacks', registrations: 'registrations' }

    resources :admins, only: [:show]
    resources :photos

    resources :locations
    resources :deals

    get 'dashboard' => 'admin_home#dashboard'



class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

   before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: 
:devise_controller?

    protected

    def after_sign_in_path_for(_resource_or_scope)
      dashboard_path
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use devise methods for this purpose where you can define paths based on some custom checks i.e., user role.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  protected  
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    sign_in_url = new_user_session_url
    if request.referer == sign_in_url
      super
    else
      stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Reference: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in

Comment: This portion worked from your link thanks. however what does "super" refer to? def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      stored_location_for(resource) ||
          if resource.is_a?(Admin)
            dashboard_path
          else
            super
          end
    end

Comment: `super` calls the method of the parent class, if it exists. It passes all the arguments to the parent class method as well. It's very useful to use for inherited classes where we want to override the method of parent class.